Disable IPV6 but your article may need an update for Unbuntu 22x
Your Topics on this are interesting and I've looked at them.
Particularly How to disable IPv6 permanently?
As a newbie, I cannot make a comment, so I am asking a question
I am on Ubuntu 22 and the information on your article won't work for me as we don't have a /etc/sysctl.conf file.
Folder under /etc:

Files under the folder:

So have you got an update for this topic that may help me make the edit in the right place?
net.ipv6.conf.all.disable_ipv6 = 1  
net.ipv6.conf.default.disable_ipv6 = 1  
net.ipv6.conf.lo.disable_ipv6 = 1  


Does this answer your question? Is there a reason sysctl is broken into so many configuration files?

Just create a new file in /etc/sysctl.d, say /etc/sysctl.d/99-disable-ipv6.conf, and put your config there. You can also still create /etc/sysctl.conf if you want and put the config there instead.

There is no such version of Ubuntu just called 22. An actual version number helps a lot.

Apologies. Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS
However, I have now found another way to disable IPv6 and remove it.
On my Plesk Server in each Domain, there was a Hosting/DNS Link. Even though I'd deleted all AAAA records on Plesk and my Control Panel, there was still a link in the Hosting/DNS to the IPV6.  Once that had gone, the job was done.
